# Round robin pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have read the article: [Performance Improvement for WCF Client Proxy Creation in .NET 3.5 and Best Practices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx) and have found mentioning about it. Still I have not found plain description.

Could someone explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scheduling algorithm. See [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79389/what-is-round-robin-scheduling)